# Number of cases- dividing squares into squares

Tags: geometry

How many cases there are when a big square(n*n) is divided into small squares?

(small square's size is does not need to be different.)

Even though the shape is the same when it rotated, we count it with another case.

Comment: I mean the square means a shape and dividing it

Comment: your answer means to a number of a square we can found on a big square and my question is to know about tiling with squares sorry i am not good at english tyty

Comment: for an example when we fill 4*4 square with 1*1 ,2*2,3*3,4*4squares it has 22 cases (tiling)

Comment: 3*3 has 6 cases like this picture
http://gall.dcinside.com/board/view/?id=hearthstone&no=2072347&page=1

Comment: Is your comment from 1613 on Mar 25 an echo of my deleted comment?  I found an error and believe the answer is $40$, which led to the OEIS entry in my answer.  I had missed cases with a $2 \times 2$ at the center of a side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sequence is given in [OEIS A045846](http://oeis.org/A045846) and begins (starting at $1 \times 1$)$$1, 2, 6, 40, 472, 10668, 450924, 35863972, 5353011036, 1500957422222, 790347882174804, 781621363452405930, 1451740730942350766748, 5064070747064013556294032, 33176273260130056822126522884, 408199838581532754602910469192704 $$  Some hand sketches that justify the $472$ for a $5 \times 5$ grid are given.  No asymptotic growth rate is given.